# PHP exec, clearing output buffer after each exec call?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP's exec function to call an application on the command line:

```
foreach($jobs as $job)
{
    exec($job['command'], $output);

    if($cmdOutput = json_decode($output[0], true))
        $log->addInfo($cmdOutput['message']);
    else
        $log->addError('Invalid JSON response');
}
```

The program from the commandline will return 1 line of output. It's always a JSON encoded string (unless there's an error that I haven't accounted for). For example:

```
{"response":false,"message":"No ads found"}
```

The problem is the output buffer isn't cleared after each run, so the value of `$output[0]` is always the same on each iteration.

How can I clear the output buffer after each iteration?

Comment: Simply use `unset($output)` after wach iteration or, even cleaner, define a _new_ buffer before each call to `exec()`: `$output = [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($jobs as $job)
{
   $output = array();
    exec($job['command'], $output);

    if($cmdOutput = json_decode($output[0], true))
        $log->addInfo($cmdOutput['message']);
    else
        $log->addError('Invalid JSON response');

   unset($output);
}
```